# How to apply background colour for the entire area instead of just the text

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css. I am not able to give background colour for the entire area, how do I do it.

MY CODE:

```html
<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            background-color: lightgray;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Horizontal List</h2>
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
        <li>HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Dor the above code only the regions have the background color, but I am looking for something like this

[image]

Instead of this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you

```css
ul {
    background-color: lightgray;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid #616161;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Horizontal List</h2>
    <div class="container">
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
       <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>  
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>  
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
       <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
       <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>  
    <ul style="width:10%; float: left;">
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>  
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How does it help, and what does it do? You should explain what you changed to help others understand it easier, best without having them dissecting your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in your css file

```
body{
 background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

I think this is what you're looking for, it will fill the entire body of the html document with chosen background color.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.full-width {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Horizontal List</h2>
    <div class="full-width">
      <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```